# Partition in a sql query, selecting only previous rows without the current one

Tags: windows, oracle, partition

Let's assume that I have the next table (sales) with the information of sales for a city in a particular month:

month 7 8 9 10

city a 10 20 30 40

If I decide to execute the next query:

```
select city, month, 
avg(sales) over (partition by city order by month rows 2 preceding) as avg
from sales
```

I will have the next result

month 7 8 9 10

city a 10 20 30 40

**avg 10 10 20 30**

This query will take the previous 2 months and the current one, but I will like to have the calculation only with the two previous months without the current one, something like this:

**avg 10 10 15 25**

Is there a way to do this?

. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should  be this one

```
select city, month, 
avg(sales) over (partition by city order by month rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding) as avg
from sales
```

or you can work even with `INTERVAL` instead of physical rows.

```
select city, month, 
avg(sales) over (partition by city order by month RANGE between NUMTOYMINTERVAL(2,'MONTH') preceding and NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH') preceding) as avg
from sales
```